# How to lock a row in a table before updating it

Tags: sql, sql-server, multithreading

To implement multi threading in SQL Server 2012 for one my update tasks, I need to have different threads select a row from a table (Accounts) and mark that row as processed using an update in a stored procedure.

Something like this:

```
create procedure ChooseNextAccountToProcess (@Account_ID Int Output)

    select top 1 @Account_ID = Account_ID 
    from Accounts 
    order by LastProcessDate Desc

    update Accounts 
    set LastProcessDate = getdate() 
    where Account_ID = @Account_ID 
go
```

The problem with this approach is that two threads might call this stored procedure exactly at the same time and process the same account. My goal is to select an account from accounts table and exclusively lock it before update has chance to update it.

I tried `SELECT .... WITH (UPDLOCK)` and `WITH Exclusive lock` but none of these can actually put exclusive lock on the row when I select that row.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why not directly update it? That will lock that row right away.

Comment: If you really need to capture the Account_ID you could do that with OUTPUT. From what you posted this really should be a single line procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `update top (n) ...`, but you can't specify `order by` directly in the statement. So, a little trick is in order:

```
declare @t table (
    Id int primary key,
    LastProcessDate date not null
);

insert into @t (Id, LastProcessDate)
values
    (1, getdate() - 10),
    (2, getdate() - 7),
    (3, getdate() - 1),
    (4, getdate() - 4);


-- Your stored procedure code starts from here
declare @res table (Id int primary key);

declare @AccountId int;

update a set LastProcessDate = getdate()
output inserted.Id into @res(Id)
from (select top (1) * from @t order by LastProcessDate desc) a;

select @AccountId = Id from @res;

-- Returns 3
select @AccountId;
```

Not exactly a one-liner, but close to it, yes.